# Organize tensorboard graph with pytorch lightning

Tags: tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I've added the default tensorboard logger (`from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger`) to my pytorch lightning Trainer with `log_graph=True`.

When I train my model, the first view of my graph shows three blocks:

*inputs => MyNetworkClassName => Outputs*

So far so good.

But then, when I expand MyNetworkClassName it gives me absolutely everything that's going on in my net. That's a lot of arrows going everywhere. I would like to organize this graph into simpler blocks with expandable subgraphs. So in my case, where my network has a typical encoder - enhancer - decoder structure, I would like something more like this:

- First graph:

  1. *inputs => MyNetworkClassName => Outputs*
- zooming in on MyNetworkClassName:

  2. *encoder => enhancer -> decoder*
- zooming in on encoder:

  3. *encoder_layer1 => encoder_layer2 => ...*
- zooming in on encoder_layer1:

  4. *conv2d => batchnorm*

What are my options here? Should I put everything into separate classes? Are there any commands that allow me to group certain actions together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refractoring code into classes also affects the tensorboard graph (where refractoring into methods does not). Typical example class that will show up as an expandable block:

```
class EncoderLayer(nn.Module):
"""Encoder layer class"""

    def __init__(self, activation_function, kernel_num, kernel_size, idx):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Sequential(
            ComplexConv2d(
            kernel_num[idx],
            kernel_num[idx + 1],
            kernel_size=(kernel_size, 2),
        ),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(kernel_num[idx + 1])
        activation_function,
    )

def forward(self, x):
    return self.layer(x)
```